# Microsoft Graph Mail - Suppressing read receipts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

We have a system that scans a mailbox periodically, processes the emails, then deletes them. When an item with a read receipt is deleted, it sends a read receipt which we want to suppress. This was possible in EWS, but we are migrating our code to Graph SDK.

How we did it in EWS:

```js
if (rawMail.IsReadReceiptRequested) rawMail.SuppressReadReceipt();
rawMail.IsRead = true; 
rawMail.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
```

This is what we tried:

```js
await graphClient.Users["userid"].Messages["messageid"].Request().Select('IsReadReceiptRequested').UpdateAsync(new Microsoft.Graph.Message() { IsReadReceiptRequested = false });
```

However, it returns this error, as if its not a valid way to deal with read receipts:

```html
ErrorInvalidPropertyUpdateSentMessage 
Message: Update operation is invalid for property of a sent message
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: was you able to solve this? If yes how? @user3665749

Comment: We blocked outbound send receipts in the transport rules in the end. Not a great solution, but only thing we had at the time. 18 months ago...

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be setting the extended properties for PidTagReadReceiptRequested https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagreadreceiptrequested-canonical-property and PidTagNonReceiptNotificationRequested directly eg a patch like this in the Graph Explorer seems to work okay

```html
{
  "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
     {
           "id":"Boolean 0x0C06",
           "value": "false"
     },
     {
    "id":"Boolean 0x0029",
           "value": "false"
     }
  ]
}
```